# Updating a global variable from within a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, variables

I am defining two variables:

```
var information;
var secondary_information;
```

I update these variables within my function:

```
async function fetchInfo() {
var num = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20 + 1);

const url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=${pos.current.coords.latitude},${pos.current.coords.longitude}&radius=12000&type=restaurant&key=${key}`;

await fetch(url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => setSearchResponse(data))
  .then(console.log("api request fired."));

let place_id = searchResponse.results[num].place_id;


const secondary_url = `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?fields=formatted_phone_number,opening_hours,formatted_address&place_id=${place_id}&key=${key}`;

await fetch(secondary_url)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((data) => setsecondarySearchResponse(data))
  .then(console.log("secondary api request fired."));

 information = {
  name: searchResponse.results[num].name,
  open_now: searchResponse.results[num].opening_hours.open_now,
  rating: searchResponse.results[num].rating,
  price: searchResponse.results[num].price_level
};

 secondary_information = {
  phone_number: secondarySearchResponse.result.formatted_phone_number,
  daily_hours: secondarySearchResponse.result.opening_hours.weekday_text,
  address: secondarySearchResponse.result.formatted_address
};
}
```

When I console log the variables from within the function it works as intended.

I am trying to pass the variables down as props to a react component but it keeps passing an empty object instead:

```
return (
<div className="App">
  <Filters />
  <Button variant="primary" onClick={fetchInfo}>
    Randomizer
  </Button>{" "}
  <Result info={information} />
</div>
);
```

Additionally, I have no clue if this is the correct way I should be going about making these API calls and storing them into state but this is the way that made sense to me. Any feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using useState in react to store your variables.
[how to use](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html)

Creating

```js
const [information, setInformation] = useState(null);
```

Updateing

```js
setInformation({
  name: searchResponse.results[num].name,
  open_now: searchResponse.results[num].opening_hours.open_now,
  rating: searchResponse.results[num].rating,
  price: searchResponse.results[num].price_level
})
```

Then passing the state to props should stay the same.

```js
<Result info={information} />
```

Comment: Okay, if I do this I will be setting state four different times in this function. Is this good practice or does it not really matter?

Comment: You should not use state to store all your variables just the ones you want to track in your application.In this case you would only use it for information and secondary_information. Look into hooks as it is big part of react.